# Looping through a file in Groovy to create JSON Template

Tags: json, groovy

I am trying to construct a JSON template for a Service in Openshift. I need to setup a groovy script that will loop through a text file containing multiple ports in order to create the port section of the JSON template.

Here is what the file containing the ports look like.

```
cat ports.txt
  9000
  8090
  7010
  6012
```

Here is my groovy script to create the template. The script contains hard coded text for port 9000.

```
def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
builder.apiVersion {
  apiVersion 'v1'
  kind 'Service'
  metadata {
    name 'apache'
    labels {
     app "apache"
     name "apache"
 }
}
spec {
selector {
  app 'apache'
 }
  ports {
  name "9000-tcp"
  protocol "TCP"
  port "9000"
  targetPort "9000"
  }
}
}
println builder.toPrettyString()
```

Running the script displays the following:

```
{
"apiVersion": {
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Service",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "apache",
        "labels": {
            "app": "apache",
            "name": "apache"
        }
    },
    "spec": {
        "selector": {
            "app": "apache"
        },
        "ports": {
            "name": "80-tcp",
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "port": "8081"
        }
    }
}
```

}

I would like the end product to look like this

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Service",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "apache",
        "labels": {
            "app": "apache",
            "name": "apache"
        }
    },
    "spec": {
        "selector": {
            "app": "apache"
        },
        "ports": {
            "name": "80-tcp",
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "port": "8081"
        }
        "ports": {
            "name": "8090-tcp",
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "port": "8090",
            "targetPort": "8090"
        }
        "ports": {
            "name": "7010-tcp",
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "port": "7010",
            "targetPort": "7010"
        }
        "ports": {
            "name": "6012-tcp",
            "protocol": "TCP",
            "port": "6012",
            "targetPort": "6012"
        }
    }
}
}
```

How can i embed a loop in this template to add create as many ports as there are in the `file.txt` file.

Answer (score 2):

The output you propose isn't valid JSON...  You cannot have multiple `ports` objects at the same level as you show...  You could however make `ports` into a list of objects like so:

```
def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
builder {
    apiVersion 'v1'
    kind 'Service'
    metadata {
        name 'apache'
        labels {
            app "apache"
            name "apache"
        }
    }
    spec {
        selector {
            app 'apache'
        }
        ports new File('ports.txt').readLines()*.trim().collect { p ->
            [name: "$p-tcp", protocol: "TCP", port: "$p", targetPort: "$p"]
        }
    }
}

println builder.toPrettyString()
```

The output from that is:

```
    {
        "apiVersion": "v1",
        "kind": "Service",
        "metadata": {
            "name": "apache",
            "labels": {
                "app": "apache",
                "name": "apache"
            }
        },
        "spec": {
            "selector": {
                "app": "apache"
            },
            "ports": [
                {
                    "name": "9000-tcp",
                    "protocol": "TCP",
                    "port": "9000",
                    "targetPort": "9000"
                },
                {
                    "name": "8090-tcp",
                    "protocol": "TCP",
                    "port": "8090",
                    "targetPort": "8090"
                },
                {
                    "name": "7010-tcp",
                    "protocol": "TCP",
                    "port": "7010",
                    "targetPort": "7010"
                },
                {
                    "name": "6012-tcp",
                    "protocol": "TCP",
                    "port": "6012",
                    "targetPort": "6012"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you tim_yates. Exactly what i am looking for. One more question for you, how do i exclude the first line of the output `"apiVersion": {` . Similar to how the output in my initial post looks like.

Comment: whoops...fixed... replaced `builder.apiVersion {` with `builder {`

Comment: You are a life saver. Thank you very much.